# instantiate service Class inside Interceptor in Nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I would call a service inside interceptor in NestJS ([see doc](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors)) , here's how I made

```
export class HttpInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    constructor(private configService:ConfigService){}
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    let request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const apikey= this.configService.get('apikey');
    const hash=this.configService.get('hash');
    request.params= {apikey:apikey ,hash:hash,ts:Date.now()}
    return next
  }
}
```

Hers's ConfigService

```
export class ConfigService {
  private readonly envConfig: { [key: string]: string };

  constructor(filePath: string) {    
    this.envConfig = dotenv.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, filePath)));
  }

  get(key: string): string {
    return this.envConfig[key];
  }
}
```

I get an error that configService is undefined

> Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

But I have instantiated `ConfigService` correctly

I don't know why I can't use `ConfigService` inside the interceptor

Comment: _But I have instantiated ConfigService correctly_ - I am not so soure: it seems that `ConfigService `is not injected - so you should post the relevant [Module definition](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules) so that we can see the providers

Comment: Could you share a bit of your code

Comment: I got response [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors#binding-interceptors) I have imported theinterceptor inside module instead of calling it inside  `main.ts`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In terms of dependency injection, global interceptors registered from outside of any module cannot inject dependencies since this is done outside the context of any module.

So if in your `main.ts` you're using

`app.useGlobalInterceptors(new HttpInterceptor());`
you will either need to change that into
`app.useGlobalInterceptors(new HttpInterceptor(new ConfigService()));`

or you can bind the interceptor in a specific module with

```
import { APP_INTERCEPTOR } from '@nestjs/core';
@Module({
  providers: [
    ConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: HttpInterceptor,
    },
  ],
})
export class YourModule {}
```

or you can bind the interceptor in a controller with

```
@UseInterceptors(HttpInterceptor)
export class YourController {}
```